# How to add layers with mapbox-gl-js custom markers?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to create custom markers, but add 2 map layers.

Essentially trying to combine this:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/

With this:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/

How do I specify my customized markers, but assign them to 2 layers?

Answer (score 4):

Markers don't exist within the map's Style, so they don't live within Layers either. They sit on top of the map, effectively within a single "layer" (but not actually a Layer).

So if you're trying to find a way to hide or show groups of markers in a single action, you'll have to find another way to do that.

Alternatively, if you really want your markers within Layers, you should create Symbol Layers with icons, not markers.